# Problem with VirtualBox in 12.10

Tags: virtualbox

When I try to start it I get:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine WindowsXp.

The virtual machine 'WindowsXp' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1.

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Machine
Interface: IMachine {5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91}
```

and in another dialog:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

'/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'

as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.
```

When I try to run:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
[sudo] password for umpirsky: 
sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: command not found
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you experience the exact same message related to libpython in 386 ?
If yes, try to install it from the console to see exactly what is the error message.
To do so, browse to your download path if you downloaded it there

```
    cd ~/Downloads/
```

run the install command

```
    sudo dpkg -i your_file.deb
```

see the error message if you experience one. Then, try to update and see if you get any dependencies issues

```
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: I would like to uninstall it first. Tried: `sudo dpkg -r virtualbox
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove virtualbox, only the config
 files of which are on the system; use --purge to remove them too
` but I can't.

Comment: Here is the log: `Makefile:181: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.`

Comment: Installed dkms and now I get `Uninstalling modules from DKMS
Attempting to install using DKMS

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.2.6/source ->
                 /usr/src/vboxhost-4.2.6

DKMS: add completed.
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
Makefile:181: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.`

Comment: It works after installing `linux-headers-generic`.

Answer (score 0):

from what I understood, it means that you tried to run the vboxdrv service but it's not installed on your system. As it should be installed with the Virtualbox installation, obviously, something was wrong

I suggest you to have a look at this topic. They installed VirtualBox from oracle binaries directly. (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1739768)

Based from my quick search, it seems to be a known issue from 12.04 (French Link : http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=1083121)

The Oracle version avoid this issue : https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: Tried and now I get this error http://i.imgur.com/uCJ1V.png. I have downloaded `Ubuntu 12.10 ("Quantal Quetzal")  i386` from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running, 32 or 64-bit? If you don't know which one, run this in Terminal: uname -a. If it shows x86_64, you have installed Ubuntu 64-bit, and need to install VBox AMD64.

Comment: Ah, right, now I was able to install AMD64, my bad, sorry. But still get same error. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm that the Oracle version does _not_ avoid the issue in any helpful way under Ubuntu 12.10. It does install the `vboxdrv` program; however, it fails with the error `Makefile:181: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.`